# openFileDialog for Adobe Air app

Tags: actionscript-3, air, openfiledialog, filepath

I have a Desktop Adobe Air app.
I want to add openFileDialog to my app to ask user for the path of his project. 
Unfortunatelly, I can't use FileReference - it returns only file name, not path.

```
    private function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
       var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
       trace("selectHandler: name=" + file.name); //only name!
    }
```

Is there any way to apply openFileDialog in such app and get the path of file, which was selected by user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`flash.filesystem.File.browseForDirectory()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForDirectory%28%29)